# Create new Opentelemetry Trace in java

Tags: java, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-java

We have traces that have hundreds/thousands of spans because of loops and that seems pretty blooded.

Is there a way to create custom Opentelemetry traces in java ? Let's say in a loop, I want to create traces on my own.

Comment: what do you mean by custom traces ? can you share some code snippent example? and some additional details like  what type of instumentation you are using ? automatic or manual ?

Comment: I mean I want to create my own traces. Currently I use opentelemetry java agent. I could not find a way to create my own trace , there is only dspan creation but I want to create my own traces

Comment: So if there is no parent span in the context it will be treated as unique trace in tracing backend.